# what does the double underscore __ mean in python?

Tags: python

What does the double underscore indicate in python?  I remember reading a tutorial that said it had something to do with a hidden variable, but I feel like there is more to it than that and I keep seeing examples of code that have double underscores and I don't understand what it means.

Comment: Depends where the double underscores are used. (`__init__`? `__name__`?)

Comment: I am asking strictly about double underscores before the name, not before and after.

Comment: @donnaloia Then it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: Are the people marking this as a duplicate also giving it downvotes? That seems unfair.

Comment: Not me.  In fact, I upvoted the question :)

Comment: I wish someone would explain this in layman's terms, even reading all the links posted, it's still confusing to me.

Answer (score 8):

From [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- `__double_leading_underscore`: when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class FooBar, `__boo` becomes `_FooBar__boo`; see below).
- `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`, `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

Comment: Good reply.  But this explains better (and also refers to the PEP 8 style guide, too): [The meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Comment: @paulsm4, strangely enough I've left a number of upvotes on that question and its answers already. As SO grows it becomes difficult to remember all the good information it contains.