# unittest in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

Below program:

```
import unittest

class my_class(unittest.TestCase):


  def setUp(self):
        print "In Setup"
        self.x=100
        self.y=200

    def test_case1(self):
        print "-------------"
        print "test case1"
        print self.x
        print "-------------"
    def test_case2(self):
        print "-------------"
        print "test case2"
        print self.y
        print "-------------"
    def tearDown(self):
        print "In Tear Down"
        print "      "
        print "      "

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Gives the output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
In Setup
-------------
test case1
100
-------------
In Tear Down

.In Setup
-------------
test case2
200
-------------
In Tear Down
      .
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.113s

OK
>>> 
>>>
```

Questions:

1. what's the meaning of: `if __name__ == "__main__": unittest.main()`?
2. Why do we have double underscores prefixed and postfixed for `name` and `main`?
3. Where will the object for `my_class` be created?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: 1. Ask one question at a time. 2. Leading and trailing double underscores are used to indicate *""magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces"*, per [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles). This prevents them clashing with the user's names (e.g. you can call a function `main`, or a variable `name`). See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19216895/3001761 3. What do you mean *"where"*?!

Answer (score 2):

The `if __name__ == "__main__":` bit allows your code to be imported as a module without invoking the `unittest.main()` code - that will only be run if this code is invoked as the main entry point of your program (i.e. if you called it like `python program.py` if your program was in `program.py`).

The prefix and postfix of double underscores means:

> `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__` : "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__` , `__import__` or `__file__` . Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

That comes from the [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) - this is a really useful resource to read and internalize.

Finally, your `my_class` class will be instantiated within the unittest framework as it runs, as it inherits from `unittest.TestCase`.